# Adding permissions back to the Windows SYSTEM user

Tags: windows, permissions

An older relative who is kind of paranoid about computer security thought it would be a good idea to remove permissions from the `SYSTEM` user (don't ask, sigh). So now the permissions on `C:\` look like this:

[image]

Clicking the `Edit` button causes the window to hang for a while before popping up a message about permissions. Is there a relatively straightforward way to get the normal `SYSTEM` permissions back without reinstalling Windows or similar?

Comment: Take ownership of the folder then remove the deny options.

Comment: And add back the allow permissions while you're at it. And tell your relative being paranoid isn't good for one's health, let alone the computer's!

Comment: It seems I can't take ownership. An attempt at that also hangs for a while before giving an error message about permissions. I can't open a command prompt as admin either; it doesn't seem like UAC works anymore. Even after booting to recovery, "refreshing" the system fails to complete, and going back to a restore point doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

**Take the hard drive out and connect it to a second Windows computer to grant the `SYSTEM` account *Allow* permissions on `C:\`.** Then put the hard drive back into the first PC and fix any remaining permissions that are incorrect below `C:\`.

Take care to simply return the Deny permissions for the `SYSTEM` to *Allow* and change as little else as possible. Changes to permissions involving built-in groups and user accounts made on the other computer will be recognized by your first PC, but if you remove any permissions for unique user accounts (such as the user account used to login the PC), you will not be able to add them back from the second computer. As long as you get the `SYSTEM` account's permissions correct on the root of `C:\` you should be able to fix the remaining permissions from the original computer which will be the best place to do this.

Comment: This is actually a laptop hard drive, so it's not terribly convenient to remove and I'd need extra hardware to have two drives connected. I might try a Linux-based recovery CD first, but your advice may be helpful for someone else.